# How to create Email authentication form for desktop application with C#?

Tags: c#, windows, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I am trying to make windows application that ask Gmail username and password from user and if it was valid go to further, anyone can help?
here is my code so far:
I don't know what to put in if() statement to check the username and password are valid

```
   private void logIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        string user, pass;
        user = userName.Text;
        pass = password.Text;
        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName.Text,password.Text)

        };
        if (//userName and password is a valid gmail account)
      {
            Options compose = new Options();
            Visible = false;
            compose.Show();
        }
        else {
            warning.Text = "Wrong Username or Password";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't known if the credentials provided are correct until you make a call to the SMTP server (you can always do basic validation of what an email address looks like, of course).

Let's say the user finishing typing up a message and you try to send it. You'll know credentials are wrong when calling the [SmtpClient.Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1s04he7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you get a `SmtpException` (make sure to read the documentations I linked to since that same exception can mean other things went wrong).

Your best bet it do that action against the SMTP server in a try/catch and catch the `SmtpException` and do something useful with it.

Comment: Tnx 4 reply but I am creating a mail merge application and I need to authenticate users at my login page the way Outlook or other similar application does....
It will not be efficient if the user goes to compose page and create message and then click send and then application authenticate the user name and password..